# In Retina mode of Cocos2D, how to autoscale PNG when -hd files are not present?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

When I enable the retina mode, and when the -hd files are not present, the normal version of .png files are shown and therefore the image looks very small. How can I autoscale those PNG files tp 2x when the -hd files are not present?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you don't.

If you're supporting Retina, you should support it all the way by providing all images in SD and HD variants. If needed, you can scale up (2x) an SD image with an image editing program. If that program uses filters (ie bicubic filtering) the upscaled image won't look as bad if you upscaled it on the fly using the scale property of sprites.

If you don't have any HD images, turn off Retina support. There's no point in supporting Retina displays if you can't provide all or most images in HD resolution.

Comment: But what if I want to use some HD images and scale the others, in order to make the bundle smaller, or make the memory consumption less? There IS a point in doing this.

Comment: Then you would load the file explicitly, and set the sprite's scale property: sprite.scale = CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();  However, such upscaled images will stick out on Retina devices like a washed out t-shirt. There is a point in doing what you try to do, but it is really BAD practice and will reflect badly on the overall quality of your app. If you have memory or app size problem, try to find other ways of reducing memory/size.

Comment: I agree there's reason to do so. I wanted to know the same thing (hence I got here). On a small pet project I'm working on I'm doing it with "pixel art" so stuff should look blocky and I can use the same graphics for retina & non-retina in the most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code to adjust the content scale factor:

```c
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setContentScaleFactor: 1.0];
```

and in CCDirectorIOS use:

```
-(void) setViewport {
     CGSize size = _winSizeInPixels;
     glViewport(0, 0, size.width * screenScale, size.height * screenScale);
}
```

It's work for me!